# How should I exclude the wrong version of a provided jar?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm having some problems with conflicting versions of some jars. I have a dependency on a library `group-a:artifact-a:0.0.1` that has a dependency on `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.1`, but I don't want that `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.1` to be included given that I know that at runtime there will be `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.2`.

How do I have to write the `pom.xml` file?

Is this one of the following correct? And what's the difference between these?

**Solution 1:**

Exclude `group-b:artifact-b` from `group-a:artifact-a:0.0.1`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>group-b</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Solution 2:**

Add `group-b:artifact-b` dependency as *provided*:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Solution 3:**

Add `group-b:artifact-b` dependency as *runtime*:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Solution 4:**

Add `group-b:artifact-b` dependency as *provided* or *runtime* and exclude it from `group-a:artifact-a:0.0.1`.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry for not being explicit, but yes @Tunaki's assumption is correct, the dependency `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.2` is not required at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 5: Just declare the version explicitly in your POM.

Maven will overwrite the transitive dependencies if you explicitly declare them in the pom. You don't need to do any mucking about with provided or runtime scope.

According to the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) (emphasis mine):

> **Dependency mediation** - this determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. **You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM.** Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.

So your pom should just be:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The correct scope should however be set for `artifact-b`.

Comment: @Tunaki It is set. Compile seems to be correct here.

Comment: I read the OP's sentence "given that I know that at runtime there will be `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.2`" as "this dependency is not required at compile-time, only at run-time". Maybe I misunderstood here.

Comment: @Tunaki You read it that way, but he doesn't give a reason why, you are making an assumption. If OP clarifies I will edit, but currently adding additional scopes adds complexity that does not appear necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use solution 4. Let's go through each solution:

### Solution 1

This is using the [exclusions principle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) of Maven. Maven resolves dependencies transitively. But when you do not want a specific transitive dependency to be included in your classpath, you can exclude it using this mechanism.

The excluded dependency will not be used at compile-time or run-time.

But this is not what you want, since you know that your project requires `group-b:artifact-b` at run-time. In this scenario, the `pom.xml` does not declare it.

### Solution 2

You are using the `provided` scope. `provided` in Maven means that this dependency is required at compile-time but should not be included in the final artifact. Typically, this dependency will be *provided* at run-time by a container, such as a web server.

As such, Maven will override the transitive dependency `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.1` of `group-a:artifact-a`. In the final dependency tree, `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.2` will be resolved as a provided dependency and *will not* be included in the final artifact (for example, if building a `war`, this library *will not* end up in `WEB-INF/lib`).

### Solution 3

This time, you are using the `runtime` scope. This is much like Solution 2.

The difference is that in the final dependency tree, `group-b:artifact-b:0.0.2` will be resolved as a run-time dependency and will be included in the final artifact (for example, if building a `war`, this library will end up in `WEB-INF/lib`).

### Solution 4

This is the same as solution 2 and 3. The difference is that Maven will not override the dependency since you are explicitely excluding it from the list of transitive dependencies of `artifact-a`. But the result will be the same.

### What is the correct solution?

This really depends on *how* your dependency will be present at run-rime. If it provided by a container, you should use Solution 4 with the `provided` scope. If not, you should use Solution 4 with the `runtime` scope.

I am suggesting this solution because:

- You are explicitely excluding the unwanted dependency from `artifact-a` transitive dependency: this makes it more clear that that specific dependency should not be used in the project.
- You are explicitely including the wanted dependency in the right scope and the right version. Again, this makes the `pom.xml` easier to read and to understand.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>group-b</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- or runtime, depending on your specific case -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I disagree, there is no reason to use provided or runtime scope here, compile time scope for artifact b seems to be correct given the information in OP's question.